# how data submitted via "/" in URL works

Tags: url, webserver

I've seen all over the internet webpages that can submit requests via the "/" for example if iIhave the URL:

```
hugelol.com/lol/63560
```

being "63560" the post I want to access to.

I was wondering if you guys could tell me how this works and if there is a way of doing it in my own pages.

Comment: Take a look at the Wikipedia entry on URLs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator. As for the server side of this, it is quite complicated and depends greatly on the specific server, how the site is built (java servlets, PHP, static HTML, etc).

Answer (score 0):

These are called [friendly urls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL).

Normally, you can achieve them by introducing some kind of interpretation mechanism in your server that can read the URL being requested and map it to an existing view (or file) with the required parameters.

For example Django, a web framework written in Python, uses regular expressions to do the parsing. A requested URL is read and is given to the Django's URL engine, which will apply several regular expressions to it until one match, extract the relevant parameters and handles it to a view.

On the other side, there is the concept of [*permalinks*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink) which hardwires an elegant URL to a web page (normally a blog). [Wordpress uses permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) to build *pretty* URLs.

Hope this helps!